# nutch - Is there a way to get http response header fields parsed?

Tags: java, http-headers, web-crawler, nutch

Can I get http respone header fields parsed with nutch?

Is it built-in capability that's need to be configured?

I've looked the internet and I can't find any info about this.

And also, if i do local file system crawling, is there a way to parse file's header? (size, description etc fields?)

Comment: How did you figure out that the response header fields are not being parsed? I assume that in order to download a page, nutch would have to parse the header field in order to (at the very least) determine what's the `Content-Length`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See line 144 [here](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/nutch/nutch-1.3/org/apache/nutch/protocol/http/api/HttpBase.java.html) . You can see that http response headers can be obtained and you can use that info.

For second question:
For parsing different file types, there are plugins provided by nutch. You need to study the same for the specific file type and get going.